# How to implement linting feature in code-mirror for a custom mode

Tags: lint, codemirror, mode, rego, ngx-codemirror

I have used ngx-codemirror and set mode to rego. Highlighting is working correctly. How should i implement lint feature for this mode.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to implement linting for CodeMirror modules, but the source code for the Rego module is available on the [Styra GitHub](https://github.com/StyraInc/codemirror-rego) if you want to work with that.